# Can't generate scripts from LocalDB in SQL Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-express, localdb, ssms-2012

I can't export scripts from my LocalDB database `(localdb)\v11.0`. (SQL Express is fine)

The error I get is

> Save or Publish Scripts Report
>
> Getting the list of objects from 'XXX'.   Failed
>
> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the
>   array. at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlScriptPublish.GeneratePublishPage.worker_DoWork(Object
>   sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) at
>   System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e) at
>   System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object
>   argument)

This is using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Does anyone know what is causing this?

Comment: Have you tried with SSMS 2012?

Comment: @ErikEJ Nope. My workmate is using 2008 R2 without any issues though.

Comment: @ErikEJ His version is newer than mine on closer inspection. I have 10.50.1617.0 and he has 10.50.20500.0

Comment: Well, latest build is 10.50.4305, so you have some old software

Comment: @ErikEJ While it wasn't immediately obvious how to update 2008, I installed SSMS 2014 which solved my issue. If you want to add as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As LocalDb is SQL Server 2012, you should use SSMS 2012 or later for this scripting task

Comment: I agree with ErikEJ. There's no reason not to use SSMS 2012 as it's backward compatible and is freely downloadable.